# Configurar Controllers Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Tengo varios Controllers y no sé si eso me está dando problemas con Symfony.
He creado los archivos manualmente, es decir, no he utilizado el comando `php bin/console make:controller` Entonces no sé si debo añadir ese Controller en alguna ruta o algo.

No detecta esta ruta del menú:
`An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "list_servicios" as such route does not exist.").`

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ path('list_servicios') }}">Servicios</a>
</li>
```

En el controller tengo:

```
/**
* @Route("/servicios", name="list_servicios")
* @Method({"GET"})
*/
public function showServicio()
{
    $servicios = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Servicio::class)->findAll();

    return $this->render('admin/list_servicios.html.twig', array('servicios' => $servicios));
}
```

El controller lo he creado manuealmente y a lo mejor por eso no lo detecta? Tengo varios Controllers.
Se podría poner algunos Controllers dentro de una carpeta dentro de src/Controller? Como se tendría que configurar?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Has hecho un controller, ya. Ahora tendrás que editar dicho controller y, según sea tu aplicación, deberás añadir las action que requieras, anotaciones de ruta... Te recomiendo que revises la doc de symfony, te explica paso a paso cómo hacer controllers completos

Comment: No me detecta algunos Controllers y no entiendo porque

Answer (score 0):

Al falta de tipo de error ya que no se ha mostrado, contestare asumiendo.

las solicitudes (de recursos) que reciben los controllers deben ser configurados en algún sitio.

Bien en el archivo "route" using el formato YAML o bien como anotaciones ("@Route/directorio/relativo/a/recurso/solicitado").

Este ultimo ira justo antes de definir tal controller. Y, previamente instala annotation. usando composer install annotation.

No se si este te ha ayudado.

Comment: el problema es que no me detecta algunos controllers y por lo tanto no me detecta algunas rutas que tengo en el menú. `<a class="nav-link" href="{{ path('list_servicios') }}">Servicios</a>` tipo esto, me pone que no encuentra list_servicios cuando en el controller tengo `/**
     * @Route("/servicios", name="list_servicios")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     */
    public function showServicio()
    {
        $servicios = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Servicio::class)->findAll();

        return $this->render('admin/list_servicios.html.twig', array('servicios' => $servicios));
    }`

Comment: Prueba el comando `bin/console debut:route` para ver si te está generando todas las rutas que has definido. Si no aparecen en el listado es que algo te falta... Pero primero comprueba con las herramientas de consola

Comment: Vale, he limpiado la caché de symfony varias veces y entonces funcionó :)